# Determine the file format(version) for old Microsoft office files

Tags: .net, file, ms-office, office-interop

I have 50k+ `.doc` files on one of our servers that users have accumulated since the early 90's.

Some of these files were created on Macintosh, or on really old version of Word.

- I've tried to look at the metadata in Word with no luck.
- I've tried to use the .NET Interop for Word and open a document to look at the properties available. Nothing jumped out at me.
- I've tried to use `FileInfo` for a series of files with no luck.

I did find a program called `Trid.exe` (http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) and if I query the doc files from 1995 it tells me they were created with MacWrite II.

How can I do the same thing with .NET?

I want to get a report of all the files first to see what were dealing with and convert files that are still needed to newer formats and delete/archive files that aren't need any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most significant part of Trid is actually written in .NET - I'd contact him directly, send a donation his way, and ask him nicely if he can share his .NET assembly or similar with you.

See http://mark0.net/code-tridengine-e.html

If you remove or relax your .NET requirement, or won't blink at invoking another process from .NET, your options open up, although I leave the final work of testing these options to you.

[DROID](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/information-management/manage-information/preserving-digital-records/droid/) from the UK National Archives is one respected open-source tool for doing this kind of identification and builds on the work of some earlier efforts. It's written in Java, though. One way to invoke it from .NET is with [the Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(VS.80).aspx). More complicated ways to start or control a Java process from .NET are available.

There are some other open-source tools available, like `libmagic` or the `file` command in recent versions of Linux, that I won't present the details of.

There are a handful of proprietary engines that might work as well. I bet you and Google can sort those out, if you wish.

Comment: It seems like such a simple thing that I would be able to find someone else looking for the same information.

If no one else responds I will talk to the Mark from that website.

Thanks Spirulence!

Comment: I've updated my answer with another tool that you might use if you relax your .NET requirement. Good luck with this project!

Comment: I do appreciate your answer.  I could use process with the Trid application and parse the output for one file at time.  It won't be pretty but it should work.

Hopefully there is a .NET solution but if not you've given me some great ideas to do this!